# jQuery Element in Variable Not Working

Tags: jquery

I am not sure why this isn't working. I am storing an element in a variable and calling it in an if statement. If I use the actual element it works but as a variable it doesn't.

```
        //General Variables 
        var $next = $('.icon-next');
        var $prev = $('.icon-previous');
```

This doesn't work:

```
        //Show Nav
        if(currentImage == 1){
          $prev.hide();
        } else {
          $prev.show();
        }
```

This does:

```
           //Show Nav
            if(currentImage == 1){
              $('.icon-previous').hide();
            } else {
              $('.icon-previous').show();
            }
```

Full scope:

```
$('a[ocular-image]').off().on('click', function(e) {

        event.preventDefault();

        //General Varibales 
        var $next = $('.icon-next');
        var $prev = $('.icon-previous');

        //get the array info
        var dataTag = $(this).attr('ocular-image');
        var ocularTags = $('.site-content').find("[ocular-image=" + dataTag + "]");

        //Get the image info
        var currentImageIndex = ocularTags.index($(this));
        var currentImage = ocularTags.index($(this)) +1;
        var totalImages = ocularTags.length;
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $(this).children().attr('title');

        //Show Nav
        if(currentImage == 1){
          $prev.hide();
        } else {
          $prev.show();
        }
});
```

Comment: Where are you defining your variables? First guess is that it's a scope issue. Can you post more of the surrounding code?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: this my 5th time review your code and I didn't find anything wrong .. try to make a Jsfiddle

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef ya, its pretty basic. Not sure if its the WordPress environment that is making something screwy.

Comment: Definitely not a scope issue then....Honestly, I'm stumped. I keep going over it, and I'm not seeing the issue. The only other guess that I can think of is the fact that it's storing a reference to the entire object range...but even that shouldn't prevent it from hiding all of them or showing them.

Comment: Do you mind posting what has the `.icon-previous` class assigned to it and how you're assigning it?

Comment: I got it. It was a scope issue. The div with `icon-previous` was being appended after the variable was made

Comment: Okay excellent! That's what I was thinking in regards to how it's storing the reference object. It's not really a scope issue, but you're simply storing the  old object reference, which doesn't include the new ones you created after the variable is created.